# How to enable click in edit action button if new row is saved jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Edit formatter action button is placed to jqgrid column:

```
colModel: [{"fixed":true,"label":" change ","name":"_actions","width":($.browser.webkit == true? 37+15: 32+15)
    ,"align":"center","sortable":false,"formatter":"actions",
"formatoptions":{"keys":true,"delbutton":false,"onSuccess":function (jqXHR) {actionresponse = jqXHR;return true;}
    ,"afterSave":function (rowID) {
    cancelEditing($('#grid'));afterRowSave(rowID,actionresponse);actionresponse=null; }
    ,"onEdit":function (rowID) {
      if (typeof (lastSelectedRow) !== 'undefined' && rowID !== lastSelectedRow)
        cancelEditing($('#grid'));
        lastSelectedRow = rowID;
        }
    }}
```

New row is added to jqgrid in loadcomplete event

```
var newRowData = {};
var newRowId = '_empty' + $.jgrid.randId();
$('#grid').jqGrid('addRowData', newRowId, newRowData);
```

and its id is updated if save action button is clicked:

```
function aftersavefunc(rowID, response) {
    restoreActionsIcons();
    $('#grid').jqGrid('resetSelection');
    var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    $("#" + rowID).attr("id", json.Id);
    lastSelectedRow = json.Id; 
    $("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', lastSelectedRow);
}
```

After clicking save action button edit action button clicks are ignored. It is not possible to re-enter to edit mode after first editing.

How to fix this so that row can edited by edit button click again after saving ?

**Update**

I added  $(this).focus() as suggested in Oleg answer and also wrapped id change into setTimeout as Oleg recommends in other great answer:

```
function aftersavefunc(rowID, response) {
    restoreActionsIcons();
    $(this).focus();
    $('#grid').jqGrid('resetSelection'); 
    var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + rowID).attr("id", json.Id);
        lastSelectedRow = json.Id;
        $("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', lastSelectedRow);
    }, 50);
}
```

Problem persists. The problem may related to row id change since:

1. It occurs only in last row (where id is changed after save). It does not occur for saved rows where responseText returns same id and row id is actually not changed.
2. It does not occur if cancel action button is pressed.

Maybe row id needs additional reset id addition to resetSelection or needs updated in somewhere other place also.

**Update2**

I added code form updated answer to errorfunc and used only english characters and numbers id ids. This allows to click multiple times but introduces additional issue:

extraparam is no more passed. If rowactions() calls are commented out, extraparam is passed with with rowactions calls extraparam is **not passed**.

I changed jqGrid source code and added alert to rowactions method:

```
alert( cm.formatoptions);
if (!$.fmatter.isUndefined(cm.formatoptions)) {
  op = $.extend(op, cm.formatoptions);
  }
```

In first clicks alert outputs 'Object'. In succeeding clicks to Save button it outputs undefined. So for unknown reason formatoptions is cleared.

Remarks to comment:

1. Absolute url in testcase is not used. Datasource is set to localarray.
   I verified that testcase works in IE and FF without external url access.
   For extraparam issue I can create new testcase.
2. Without image directory buttons are shown in cursor is moved over them.
   Missing image directory still allows to reproduce the issue.
3. FormData function is defined in js file.

Since new issue occurs after adding rowactions() calls and does not occur if those calls are removed, this seems to be related to the code proposed in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the problem exist because one hide a button which has currently focus. Look at the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126810/jqgrid-inline-edit-save-handler-when-clicking-enter). If one remove the line `$(this).focus(); // set focus somewhere` one has the same problem as you describes. So I suggest that you just try to set somewhere, for example in `restoreActionsIcons` the focus to any the `table` element of the grid after hiding the button having currently the focus. I can't test this, but I hope it will help.

**UPDATED**: I examined your problem one more time and I hope I can suggest you a solution.

You problem can be divided on two sub-problems. The main your problem is the the *changing of the id of the row*. So it is not common problem which everybody has.

The problem is that "actions" formatter create `onclick` functions directly in the HTML code (see for example [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L468)):

```
ocl = "onclick=$.fn.fmatter.rowactions('"+rowid+"','"+opts.gid+"','edit',"+opts.pos+");..."
```

So the functions will contains the **original** rowid. To fix the problem you can modify the code fragment of your `aftersavefunc` inside of `setTimeout` from

```
$("#" + rowID).attr("id", json.Id);
lastSelectedRow = json.Id;
$("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', lastSelectedRow);
```

to something like the following:

```
var $tr = $("#" + rowID),
    $divEdit = $tr.find("div.ui-inline-edit"),
    $divDel = $tr.find("div.ui-inline-del"),
    $divSave = $tr.find("div.ui-inline-save"),
    $divCancel = $tr.find("div.ui-inline-cancel");

$tr.attr("id", json.Id);
if ($divEdit.length > 0) {
    $divEdit[0].onclick = function () {
        $.fn.fmatter.rowactions(newId,'grid','edit',0);
    };
}
if ($divDel.length > 0) {
    $divDel[0].onclick = function () {
        $.fn.fmatter.rowactions(newId,'grid','del',0);
    };
}
if ($divSave.length > 0) {
    $divSave[0].onclick = function () {
        $.fn.fmatter.rowactions(newId,'grid','save',0);
    };
}
if ($divCancel.length > 0) {
    $divCancel[0].onclick = function () {
        $.fn.fmatter.rowactions(newId,'grid','cancel',0);
    };
}
lastSelectedRow = json.Id;
$("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', lastSelectedRow);
```

The second problem is that you use special characters inside of ids. I found a bug in the [$.fn.fmatter.rowactions](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L394) which need be fixed to support special characters in ids. The problem is that in the line [407](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L407) of `jquery.fmatter.js` the original rowid parameter `rid` will be changed:

```
rid = $.jgrid.jqID( rid )
```

and later everywhere will be used modified id. For example in the id is `my.id` the encoded version will be `my\\.id`. It's correct for the most places of the [$.fn.fmatter.rowactions](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L394) code (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)), but it' s incorrect as the rowid parameter of the `editRow`, `saveRow`, `restoreRow`, `delGridRow`, `setSelection` and `editGridRow` (see the lines [433](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L433)-[453](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L453)). So the code must be fixed to use the **original not escaped (not encoded)** `rid` value with which the [$.fn.fmatter.rowactions](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L394) was called.

I think I will post tomorrow the corresponding bug report with the suggestions in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/).

**UPDATED 2**: The code `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions(newId,'grid','edit',0);` which I wrote above is **just an example**. I took it from the test demo which you send me. You should of course **modify** the code for your purpose. How you can see for example from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L474) the second parameter of the `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions` in the id of the grid which you use: 'grid', 'list' of something like `myGrid[0].id`. The last parameter should be the *index* of the column having `formatter:'actions'` in the `colModel`. You can use `getColumnIndexByName` function from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575192/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-row-based-on-row-cell-value-by-column-name/6575634#6575634) on your old question to get the index by column name.

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented change you recommended but problem persists. I updated question and testcase.

Comment: @Andrus: I wrote you before in an comment the following tip: if you change the `id` of some row of grid you have to examine at least `selrow` string and `selarrrow` array for the `id` values which you change. If needed you have to update the values immediately after changing row id with `jQuery.attr`.

Comment: Thank you. In code provided `$('#grid').jqGrid('resetSelection')` is called before row id change. I looked into resetSelection source code and it looks like it sets selarrow to [] and selrow to null. So I dont understand why those values needs to be examined.

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, I didn't seen the statement. I suppose you should try to reduce the code to create small demo which has the described problem. I still think that you can solve the problem setting the focus, but you should find the place where you have to do this. If I set many breakpoints to debug your testcase the problem disappears (debugger have to set focus), so the problem is difficult to analyse.

Comment: Thank you. I created standalone testcase and sent it to you. I do'nt know how to emulate Edit url success event locally, so I moved this code to errorfunc in testcase

Comment: @Andrus: I think I found the reason of your problems. See "Updated" part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. First testcase which I sent contains also `extraparam:{_dokdata:FormData}` in actions formatoptions. After adding changes from answer _extraparam is no more passed to Edit controller. How to fix this? Also: Id changing is required if new row is added without grid refresh. This is common requirement. I don't know how to implement this common requirement without changing row id as in my sample.

Comment: @Andrus: I don't promise you to find all bugs in your code. I don't make free worldwide support to solve any problems. Your first testcase contains jqGrid having absolute `url`. It can probably work on your computer and only in IE, but it can't work at me. Without `images` directory the testcase display just empty grid. The program has undefined `FormData` variable. I believe that your program have more bugs, but you should solve it yourself. Do you tried to implement the suggestion which I described? Can you now click on "Edit" button?

Comment: thank you very much for great answer and comment. I updated question and answered in this update

Comment: @Andrus: I suppose you used wrong index as the last parameter of `$.fn.fmatter.rowactions`. See "Update 2" in my modified answer.

Comment: thank you. I used grid and colmodel from testcase . actions is first column so based my understanding its index is 0 always. grid id is grid always.

Comment: @Andrus: Depend on other parameters which you use `multiselect: true`, `rownumbers: true` or `subGrid: true` the index can be 1, 2 or even 3 instead of 0. Do you tried to get the index with respect of `getColumnIndexByName` or just examine the `colModel` **after** the grid is created? You can also just use Developer Tools (started by F12) of Internet Explorer or Google Chrome to examine the grid. I suppose in your grid the index will be 1 or 2 instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used wrong index. I'm sorry for that. Using getColumnIndexByName solves the issue. Thank you again Oleg, your help is really great.

Comment: I removed `setTimeout` and `$('#grid')[0].focus()` calls which you suggested to add. It seems that code works ok without those calls. It it safe to remove them ?

Comment: @Andrus: If you have no problem: why should to have the unneeded code?

Comment: In 4.4.4 rowactions code uses $(this) and thus rowactions calls used in answer do not work. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus: The answer is 1,5 years old. It was about *another* version of jqGrid. I can remind that I posted some suggestions to trirand (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/e23c95e281b2eea52f4e1aa36d73b5f83cc91dec)) to rewrite code of formater actions so that renaming of `id` will be more easy. You should post new question where you describe which problem you have with the jqGrid 4.4.4.

Comment: @Andrus: See [the commit](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/e23c95e281b2eea52f4e1aa36d73b5f83cc91dec) Nov 08, 2012. So already version 4.4.2 version should have the modification included. Which version of jqGrid use you?

Comment: I upgraded to 4.4.4 It seems that 4.4.4 works OK without this code, I removed it.

Comment: @Andrus: It was the goal of [my suggestion](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commit/e23c95e281b2eea52f4e1aa36d73b5f83cc91dec). I changed the parameters of `jQuery.fn.fmatter.rowactions` so that it uses `$(this).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")` instead of *static* parameter `opts.gid` which represents the id of row at the moment of creating of last filling of the grid. New version of the code should work correctly even after changing the value of id attribute of the row.